# What is the Java equivalent to a multi dimensional object in Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have an Android game in which I want to store levels as a static Java class.
What is the equivalent of the following Javascript object in Java?

```
var Levels = {
Level1:{
    shapes:[
    {
        bodytype : "dynamic",
        h : "50.0000",
        nameid : "hofN7-1",
        props : {
            id : "properties"
        },
        rotation : "0.0000",
        type : "square",
        uid : "Av2EZQh",
        w : "50.0000",
        x : "20.0000",
        y : "20.0000"
    },
    {
        bodytype : "dynamic",
        h : "50.0000",
        nameid : "hofN7-2",
        props : {
            gravMassScale : "2",
            id : "properties",
            inertia : "2",
            isBullet : true,
            torque : "2",
            velocity : {
                x : "2",
                y : "2"
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: I think `Map` is the nearest in behaviour, if you don't want to create a new class (or many new classes).

Comment: Maybe you should learn the java basics first?

Comment: Classes and attributes are what you are looking for. Basic OOP.

Comment: I think you should not store data as Java class. Rather, you should design some kind of file structure (can be a JSON file) to store the levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something close to how JS stores objects, you can try JSONObject class:

```
http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html
```

Keeping Syntax-to-Syntax mapping aside, from an engineering perspective, I would store levels in a map of Levels like so:

```
HashMap<String, Level> myLevels = new HashMap<String, Level>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters wrote, you can use a `Map` to create an equivalent object in Java. However, the values in this map are of different types. Some would be `String`s.  Some would be arrays of some type of `Object`.  Some would be `Map`s themselves.

The only collection object you could use then is `Map<String, Object>`, and then you would need to make `instanceof` checks each time you used it. This would be clumsy.

You could use a JSON binding library, like Jackson. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome. This has a mode where you create a class, `Levels`, and annotates its instance variables so Jackson can turn instances into JSON and back. But you need to know your class structure for that.  Jackson has a mode where it can use untyped maps.

Finally, you can model `Levels` by treating it as a tree and using the Composite pattern.  You'd have a `Node` abstract class that holds a name, and concrete subclasses like `IntegerNode`, `StringNode`, `DoubleNode`, `MapNode`, and `ArrayNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Take this adjusted version of your JSON and create the classes using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/):

```
{
  "Levels":{
    "shapes":[
    {
      "bodytype" : "dynamic",
      "h" : "50.0000",
      "nameid" : "hofN7-1",
      "props" : {
          "id" : "properties"
      },
      "rotation" : "0.0000",
      "type" : "square",
      "uid" : "Av2EZQh",
      "w" : "50.0000",
      "x" : "20.0000",
      "y" : "20.0000"
    },
    {
      "bodytype" : "dynamic",
      "h" : "50.0000",
      "nameid" : "hofN7-2",
      "props" : {
        "gravMassScale" : "2",
        "id" : "properties",
        "inertia" : "2",
        "isBullet" : "true",
        "torque" : "2",
        "velocity" : {
          "x" : "2",
          "y" : "2"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Check `JSON` for conversion and choose other options as you need them. You can download and use use the converted classes in you Java project.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: This is a great answer but I was more looking for how to do it as a Java object for the purposes of my project.

Comment: The resulting classes can be used for JSON/POJO conversions with many parsers like *genson*, *gson* or the Android built-in package (`org.json.*`). They implement in fact an object representation of any JSON data - once instantiated :)